# Disable cross-database access

Tags: sql-server

Lets say User1 has access to both Db1 and Db2.

Where the DB1 and Db2 reside in the same SQL Server box.

Now with the following syntax this user can access tables from other database:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [database].[schema].[table]
```

I have a security requirement that I am working on that should restrict cross-database queries.

The user will have access to both the dbs, it is just that I need a way to restrict executing queries on different servers.

Comment: If they need access at all, why are we trying to restrict them from selecting?

Comment: They need access to multiple dbs but query one DB at a time. believe me this is a valid business case.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot restrict cross database queries for users that have the appropriate permissions in all involved databases.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible what you ask for.

However, your best bet is to deny select from tables as a general rule, and only allow select from views and executing stored procedures. This way you can control who can do what in which context, and fail gracefully on an attempt to do otherwise.

Comment: The select statement are meant to create Adhoc reports through report Builder 3.0. You can query a SP. It can be a predefined view as this is a adhoc

Comment: Ad hoc queries can target views. However, it's a business decision, not the technical one.